# Error: UiPath, Input dialog with variable as int32 type results in error

Tags: rpa, uipath

I downloaded and installed UiPath studio community edition 2018.2.4 running on my Windows 7 ultimate 64 bit with .net 4.0.30319 edition

By following this [Tutorial Link](https://www.uipath.com/tutorials/control-flow) I created a simple sequence process with

1. Input dialog
2. if-else condition

When I created a variable with `Scope` specific to `sequence` and changed its `data type/variable type` to `int32`, i get an error message.

[image]
The error message is *one or more children has validation errors or warning*

**error stack**

> The workflow has validation errors. Review and resolve them first.
>
> System.Activities.InvalidWorkflowException: The workflow has validation 
>   errors. Review and resolve them first. ---> 
>   System.Activities.ValidationException: Compiler error(s) encountered 
>   processing >expression "year".Invalid L-value expression.:Reference 
>   expressions cannot end >with Conversion. The provided expression's type must 
>   exactly match the type T >of VisualBasicReference or LambdaReference.
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

**Where I am going wrong?** This doesn't happen when I keep the `variable type` to `UiPath.Core.GenericValue` but any other `variable type` I am faced with this error message.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a variable by "right click and choose create variable" ( ctrl + k ). It create a "GenericValue" variable.
You change it to "Int32". That's why you are getting error.

Solution:
Delete "year" variable on "Output/Result" and write "year" again ( Tips: when you write "y", it supports to come drop down list contains "year". If not, "backspace" to delete all letter in "Result", "backspace" on more time and try again )

Comment: According to the tutorial video, they change the type after doing the CTRL + K and it works. IMHO, if we create variables with CTRL+K and later if we cannot change the type of it within the scope, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You can change variable's type whenever you want. But you have let UiPath adapt it by clean the variable ( wherever you are using it ) and type it in again.